# How to show top 10 cpu util processes in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I need show  top 10 CPU utilization process in windows 2008 server. In powershell get-process have cpu output but it gives cpu time but not CPU utilization. I searched lot of forums, i dint find anything clearly.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Thread |   ?{$_.Name -notmatch '_Total'} | sort PercentProcessorTime -desc | select -first 10 | ft -auto Name,IDProcess,IDThread,PercentProcessorTime
```